# Argparse positional arguments with prefix

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

My python3 script works with the input and the output file which is specified on the command line.
The usage should looks like this

```
xxxx.py [-h] --input=file --output=file
```

In code I am using

```
parser.add_argument("input", help='Input file');
parser.add_argument("output", help='Output file');
```

but the arguments are without the necessary prefix. Is there a way to specify the prefix for each argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply include the double-dash:

```
parser.add_argument("--input", help='Input file');
parser.add_argument("--output", help='Output file');
```

Arguments are either positional or optional; arguments starting with `--` are *always* optional. You cannot create positional arguments with a `--` prefix and you really should not. The `--` prefix is a user interface convention you really do not want to break.

Comment: I agree and understand what you mean but this format is defined in my assignment for class so I cannot change it.
In this case I guess I will treat them as optional and then check if both of them were defined in command line but I don't like this solution at all because it messes up the automatically generated help option.

Comment: @skornos: I suspect you are misinterpreting the assignment in that case.